# How to open SWRevealViewController from a button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile, xcode6

I'm a complete newbie in XCode/iOS development and I am trying to create a navigation menu. I followed [Appcoda's Slideout Sidebar-Menu Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) and managed to get it to work. It opens great when the SWRevealViewController is the initial ViewController.

Right now, I have a landing page that has a Button, and when I click on it, I want it to be navigated to SWRevealViewController.

I tried this codes to open SWRevealViewController doing this on button click, but it's not showing, and the codes worked on other UIViewController.

`SWRevealViewController *menu = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];`

Can someone guide me on why and how I could achieve what I want? This could be a stupid question but I need help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: show the screen shot , i m not get in your point

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik uploaded the screen shot as requested. sorry for the small font. the first one is the view controller with button. the second is the SWRevealViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the following code. I hope it will be helpful to you

**Step 1 :** Just provide storyboard reference to you're SWRevealViewController and then in you're button action write the following code

**In Objective-C**

```
 SWRevealViewController *revealVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"swRevealViewContoller"];
                revealVC.delegate=self;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController = revealVC;
```

**In Swift:**

```
//MARK: searchBtnClicked
@IBAction func searchBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swRevealViewContoller") as? SWRevealViewController
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController = nextViewController;
}
```

If you are facing this kind of issues just take it as "rootViewController" then enjoy you're coding..

Comment: It should be push, not to replace root view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
let myRevealViewControl:SWRevealViewController = self.revealViewController()
    let myStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myDest = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage") as! UIViewController
    let myNewFrontView = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: myDest)
    myRevealViewControl.pushFrontViewController(myNewFrontView, animated: true)
```

Comment: If SWRevealViewConttoller itself is in different storyboard, self.revealViewController() wont work. Any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
menuButton.addTarget(revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```